# Website posting and login

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make website where the moderator will be able to publish a post or an image without accessing to the code. To publish something like a facebook status from some part of site. And second question, who can I make that someone can login to my site(moderator/administrator), I know how to make login form but just visualy withaout some functionality. Thanks
(I know HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You'll need to look up any of a large number of server-side programming languages / platforms.  C#.Net, Java, NodeJS, Ruby on Rails, Python / Flask / Django, etc etc etc.  Pick one (maybe NodeJS since you already know Javascript) and hit up the Getting Started tutorials.

Comment: If you have no clue how to tackle this I'd suggest you pick an open source project the meets your requirements and start tinkering instead of trying to create something from scratch.

Comment: I'll try a little more precisely, I created HTML website, I stylized him with CSS and add some function with JavaScript, now I want to make some some textbox on my site where moderator can enter new post and publish them on website, now if I want change content of website I must change it on HTML code, I want make some textbox where person who don't now codding can just enter post and publish them. Like on Facebook where you enter post and publish them. I hope you understand me better now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You seem to be talking about a [Content Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). I'd suggest you look at some of the ([many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems)) options out there
e.g.  Wordpress or Drupal - neither is perfect but both are widely supported.

Comment: I don't understand you, I built my website with HTML,CSS, JS. How can I use Wordpress now?

Comment: If you have already build your site then it's going to be harder. You can have your code pick up images or HTML files from a given folder that the users have access too _BUT_ there are significant security risks involved in doing that at a basic level. I'd suggest not going down that route & looking at migrating to a CMS of some sort